# String Compare To, Alphabet order

Tags: java

I am trying to take two words and return the word that comes first in the alphabet (It should also ignore if the word starts with a capital letter)

My Code so far (EDIT):

```
public String whatComesFirst(String Name1, String Name2) {

    if(Name1.compareToIgnoreCase(Name2) < 0) {
        return Name1 + " comes before " + Name2 + " in the alphabet";
    }
    if (Name1.compareToIgnoreCase(Name2) > 0) {
        return Name2 + " comes before " + Name1 + " in the alphabet";
    }
    return Name1;
}
```

However, it does not give out the words in an alphabetic order...

EDIT:

I think I got it now.
Does that look about right:

```
public String whatComesFirst(String Name1, String Name2) {

if(Name1.compareToIgnoreCase(Name2) < 0) {
    return Name1 + " comes before " + Name2 + " in the alphabet";
}
if (Name1.compareToIgnoreCase(Name2) > 0) {
    return Name2 + " comes before " + Name1 + " in the alphabet";
}
if (Name1.compareToIgnoreCase(Name2) == 0) {
    return Name1 + " is the same as " + Name2;
}
return Name1;
```

Comment: It should work after your (first) edit. How are you calling it?

Comment: After the edit: Your last return should be for the case where Name1 and Name2 have the same value. So you probably should print a sentence saying that

Comment: unuseful if (Name1.compareToIgnoreCase(Name2) == 0) {
    return Name1 + " is the same as " + Name2;
}. You can write only     return Name1 + " is the same as " + Name2;

Comment: Also one note: Try to stick to Java coding conventions and use small letters for variables (in your case Name1 and Name2 should be name1 and name2)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
public String whatComesFirst(String name1, String name2) {
    if (name1.equalsIgnoreCase(name2))
        return name1 + " is the same as " + name2;
    if (name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2) < 0) {
        return name1 + " comes before " + name2 + " in the alphabet";
    }
    return name2 + " comes before " + name1 + " in the alphabet";
}
```

regards